# Logic (Sentence Negation)

Tags: logic

Please note that while this is a homework question, I'm simply asking for fact checking and explanations to my solution.

Sentence: If the file is not damaged and the processor is fast, then the printer is slow

My Solution:

Symbolic Translation:  $(F'∧ P) → S$

Negation:

1. $((F'∧ P) → S)'$
2. $(F ∧ P') → S'$
3. $((F ∧ P') → (S'))'$
4. $(F' ∨ P) ∧ S$         --could the negation end here?
5. $((F')' ∨ P') ∧ S$
6. $(F ∨ P') ∧ S$

I'm kind of stuck from fixing the errors highlighted by Hunan and Ross. I'm not sure if I should proceed with steps 5 and 6

Comment: I probably don't understand the problem here.  If 0. denotes [(F'∧P)→ S] the negation of 0. comes as 1. ((F'∧ P) → S)'.  The negation of 1. comes as logically equivalent to 0.

Comment: That makes sense to me, the english translation would then be "If the file is damaged and the processor is not fast, then the printer is not slow.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work as an English translation.  You can write (F'∧P) as ∧ 'F P, and (Q→S) as → Q S.  If you do this, then [(F'∧P)→ S] can become → ∧ 'F P S.  It's negation comes as  ' → ∧ 'F P S.  I've done this to make it clear you've negated the *conditional* sentence here.  So, the negation of [(F'∧P)→ S] can get read "it is not the case that if the file is not damaged and the processor is fast, then the printer is slow."  That comes as truth-functionally equivalent to saying "it is the case that the file is not damaged and the processor is fast, and the printer is not slow."

Comment: Which [rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Basic_and_derived_argument_forms) did you use to get from  1. ((F'∧ P) → S)' to 2. (F ∧ P') → S'?

Answer (score 1):

I check the following statements statement

1. $((F'∧ P) → S)'$
2. $(F ∧ P') → S'$

by the truth table generator by [Samuel Williams](http://programming.dojo.net.nz/study/truth-table-generator/index) and by [John Halleck's Expression Evaluator](http://home.utah.edu/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/nahaj/evaluate.cgi).

I translate them in a slighly different notation that can be understood by the [truth table generator](http://programming.dojo.net.nz/study/truth-table-generator/index)

1. ~((~F& P) -> S)
2. (F & ~P) -> ~S

First put  ~((~F& P) -> S)  in the [generator](http://programming.dojo.net.nz/study/truth-table-generator/index). You get

```
            !
F  P  S  |  ~  (  (  ~  F  &  P  )  ->  S  )
--------------------------------------------
0  0  0  |  0        1  0  0  0      1  0     
0  0  1  |  0        1  0  0  0      1  1     
0  1  0  |  1        1  0  1  1      0  0     
0  1  1  |  0        1  0  1  1      1  1     
1  0  0  |  0        0  1  0  0      1  0     
1  0  1  |  0        0  1  0  0      1  1   
1  1  0  |  0        0  1  0  1      1  0     
1  1  1  |  0        0  1  0  1      1  1
```

The result for the expression is ion the column I marked with *!*

Now do the same with the second expression  (F & ~P) > ~S

```
                               !
F  P  S  |  (  F  &  ~  P  )  ->  ~  S
--------------------------------------
0  0  0  |     0  0  1  0      1  1  0  
0  0  1  |     0  0  1  0      1  0  1  
0  1  0  |     0  0  0  1      1  1  0  
0  1  1  |     0  0  0  1      1  0  1  
1  0  0  |     1  1  1  0      1  1  0  
1  0  1  |     1  1  1  0      0  0  1  
1  1  0  |     1  0  0  1      1  1  0  
1  1  1  |     1  0  0  1      1  0  1
```

Th column marked with *!* differ so you made an error. Only if both columns match your derivation is right.

For the [evaluator](http://home.utah.edu/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/nahaj/evaluate.cgi) we need the following translation

1. ~((~F& P) > S)
2. (F & ~P) > ~S

We put   (~((~F& P) > S))=((F & ~P) > ~S)  in the evaluator and get the result

> We find that it is **contingent**, for example:
>
> - (p=T s=F ) gives a true evaluation.
> - (p=F s=F ) gives a false evaluation.

If the expression is **TRUE** the your derivation is ok, if it is 
*contingent* or **FALSE** you made an error.

The truth-table method you can used by calculating by hand.
You must not calculate the values for all combinations of $F$, $P$ and $S$ to see that your derivation is false. e.g.for  $P=0$, $S=0$, $F=0$ the first expression is $0$ and the second is $1$, so you have an error.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 and 2 look the same to me.  From step 2 to step 3 is not correct.  $A \rightarrow B$ is only false when $A$ is true and $B$ is false.  Your transition from step 3 to step 4 is the right type for step 2 to step 3.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for answering. After applying the suggested edits can the negation terminate at step 4?

Comment: The passage from 1 to 2 is still incorrect, as is from 2 to 3 and from 3 to 4. 4 would be a fine end point, were it correct. The rule for negating an implication is $(a \to B)' becomes $A \wedge B'$

Answer (score 0):

$\fbox{Original}$ $(\overline{F} \land P) \rightarrow S$ (i've replaced your negation style)

$\fbox{Your attempt to negate it}$

1. $\overline{((\overline{F} ∧ P)→S)}$ $\color{green}\checkmark$ (hyp)
2. $\overline{((\overline{F} ∧ P)→\overline{S})}$  $\color{red}\chi$ (*doesn't follow from 1*)
3. $\overline{(\overline{F} ∧ P)} → \overline{(\overline{S})}$ $\color{green}\checkmark$ (from 2)
4. $\overline{(\overline{F} ∧ P)} ∧ S$ $\color{red}\chi$ (*doesn't follow from 3*)
5. $(\overline{(\overline{F})} ∨ \overline{P}) ∧ S$ $\color{green}\checkmark$ (from 4)
6. $(F ∨ \overline{P}) ∧ S$ $\color{green}\checkmark$ (from 5)

So, it fails for those two reasons. You explicitly asked not to give you the solution, so I won't.

Comment: Hi Hunan, thanks for replying. I edited the negation steps and I'm kind of stuck now. With my most recent edits could the negation end at step 4?

Comment: Np. Now steps (3, 4, 5) don't follow. May I ask why you don't want to get rid of the conditionals and work with disjunction, conjunction, negation, and a bunch of De Morgans? Unless you're explicitly asked to practice with arrows, just transform (A -> B) to (~A v B) and work from there. It should take about three moves to reduce the formula.